# How to compile Ubuntu from source

Tags: compiling

I am looking for a procedure to build Ubuntu (LTS) from the source including xwindow. 
The goal is to prepare for my platform of embedded SoC (ARM64) based device.

Comment: There is no "Ubuntu source". Ubuntu is made of many packages each one has its own source.

Comment: What do you mean with 'building from the source'? Ubuntu is a distribution, based on a Linux kernel with a set of (precompiled) packages. If you'd like to compile every package by yourself, there are more suitable distros (Arch, Gentoo, maybe a BSD), even if it is not impossible to do it with Ubuntu. But than the question should be mire specific... If you'd like to create your own flavored base installation (beside from Kubuntu, Ubuntu Studio, Lubunu, ...), take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization